# Garbage value stored by std::tuple

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement Variadic template. However I am facing a strange issue which I am not able to resolve from quite a long time.

Below is sample code (which is reproducing the same problem):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<tuple>

template<typename... Args> struct Print_Helper
{
        const std::tuple<const Args&...>& argTuple;

        Print_Helper(const std::tuple<const Args&...>& argTuple)
                :argTuple(argTuple)
        {

        }
};


        template<typename fmtType,typename...Args> Print_Helper<const Args&...>
Print(fmtType fmt,const Args&... args)
{
        Print_Helper<const Args&...> ipH(std::tuple<const Args&...>(args...));
        return ipH;
}

template<typename... Args>
void otherFunc(Print_Helper<const Args&...> obj)
{
        std::cout<<std::get<0>(obj.argTuple)<<"\n";
}

int main()
{

        auto obj = Print("i=%", 1234);
        std::cout<<std::get<0>(obj.argTuple)<<"\n";
        otherFunc(obj);

}
```

The problem is that in `main()` function when I tried printing the first element of tuple it gets printed correctly. However, when I try passing the object (in which tuple is stored) and try retrieving the value of first argument it gives me garbage.

Please help. I am trying to understand the problem from long time but not getting the exact issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have dangling reference as your member is a const reference, and you provide a temporary:

```
Print_Helper<const Args&...> ipH(std::tuple<const Args&...>(args...));
//                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//                                 Temporary
// From now, ipH.argTuple is dangling.
```

Comment: Can you please explain a bit. Also, what can be the best way to resolve it?

Comment: Store by value, not const reference. If you want efficiency - add move ctor

Comment: You will have the issue even without `tuple`: `struct S { const int & ref }; S s(int(42));`, `s.ref` is dangling. A solution is to make a copy, but not sure of what you want.

Comment: Sorry but I tried saving it by value too and I even then I am getting garbage.

Comment: I got the problem now.. But I have one question now.. I can have few clases where a given class is not copy constructible.. So I should pass that class type as ref only. In this scenario I could not pass by vlaue. What should I do now?